# Is an "R connection" really all we care about in terms of personal identity?

Tags: identity

Derek Parfit in his article *Reasons and Persons* brings the following scenario - your brain is split in 2 pieces, each capable of surviving on their own, and transplanted into 2 other people (Righty and Lefty). Now, we might think that this scenario poses a problem, since it's unclear whether or not you survive, but Parfit claims that even though we can't answer the question of whether or not you survived (since it doesn't make sense to say you didn't, nor that arbitrarily either Righty or Lefty is you, nor can you be 2 people), that shouldn't matter, that's not what we care about, what we care about is having a certain psychological connection, what he calls an "R connection", and since we have that with both Righty and Lefty it doesn't matter whether or not you as a person survived. 
But is this really true? It seems to me, that in terms of pure selfishness, I don't care as much about either Righty or Lefty as much as I do about my own future self, shouldn't that impact the issue?